How relevant are computer science concepts to discuss the ontological complexity of a theory?
From a question I asked here, in regards to god's inherent complexity in comparison to the universe, Richard Carrier uses many computer science concepts to discuss the complexities of these theories. From further research, it seems that a good amount of philosophers have already began to use ideas from computer science (such as Kolmogorov complexity or Minimum message length).
As an example, Graham Oppy, a philosopher, uses MML to make the argument that neither a designer nor the multiverse hypothesis explains the fine tuned universe. MML, in a nutshell, is similar to MDL (minimum description length), which in turn refers to a principle where the shortest description of the data is the best model to explain that very data. As the wiki on it states, "MDL methods learn through a data compression perspective and are sometimes described as mathematical applications of Occam's razor".
So, given that computer science principles have been used to mathematically define Occam's razor, which is a principle rooted in philosophy, these principles seem useful. On the other hand, since the universe and many other things aren't actually running on computer processors, how relevant are these principles when it comes to analyzing the ontological complexity of a theory?

Welcome! Some outstanding questions. :D Make sure you read the FAQ! https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Much of computer science is just math, and the "computer" bit is convenience and practicality more than anything.  For example, ChatGPT is just a bunch of casting strings to vectors and then tensor math and then casting vectors back to strings.  Those calculations are all addition, multiplication, etc, and could theoretically be done on pencil and paper, if one had a million years and a billion pages on which to perform them.

A perhaps relevant example is fractals like the Mandelbrot Set, showing infinite variation and depth of complexity based on one simple function.

Organic Chemistry: way way more molecular combinations than inorganic chem, using only CHON.

The idea here is 'generativity' - "the quality of being able to produce or create something new". Take a look in to that and see if it helps.

I mean reality is a fuzzy difficult to grasp mess. While with math and in extension computer science we're dealing with universes of our own creation where we control the big bang and the interaction between objects ... by definition. So if we can build structures in our minecraft world that mimic the (measurements of the) real world and we understand how and why they are happening in our toy examples, that can help us understand what's actually happening.

Philosophy often uses intuitions and metaphors to make sense of claims and arguments, and therefore both mathematics and computation are fundamentally powerful languages for making arguments within philosophy. When we talk about the complexity of the universe, we make use of the notion of mathematical structure. This is mathematical thinking. When we talk about transformation in the universe, we make use of the notion of computation. And if we are talking about a supreme being, then it seems right to intuit about such a being in a way we are familiar with when discussing concepts in the philosophy of mind, the notions of the computational theory of mind (SEP), neuroscience of consciousness (SEP), and representational theories of consciousness (SEP).
Plus, when you get down to it, there are deep connections between mathematics, logic, and programs, a result known as the Curry-Howard Correspondence. From WP:

It is a generalization of a syntactic analogy between systems of formal logic and computational calculi that was first discovered by the American mathematician Haskell Curry and the logician William Alvin Howard. It is the link between logic and computation that is usually attributed to Curry and Howard, although the idea is related to the operational interpretation of intuitionistic logic given in various formulations by L. E. J. Brouwer, Arend Heyting and Andrey Kolmogorov (see Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov interpretation) and Stephen Kleene (see Realizability). The relationship has been extended to include category theory as the three-way Curry–Howard–Lambek correspondence.

Thus, if it makes sense to philosophize about God and the Universe using the language of logic, or the language of mathematics, then necessarily, one would be hard pressed to omit the language of computation, particularly if one embraces a naturalized epistemology (SEP) In this view, computer science is continuous with philosophy as an enterprise, and has interesting parallels with traditional philosophical questions, such as how software-hardware duality appears to resemble mind-body duality.
You might also be interested in the following articles:

Philosophy of Computer Science (SEP)
Computational Philosophy (SEP)
Computation in Physical Systems (SEP)
Computational Complexity Theory (SEP)
Computational Theory of Mind (SEP)


Algorithmic information theory is a branch of mathematics that formalizes certain intuitions of "randomness" and "order". The core idea is that a random string is an uncompressible string. This theory can give you some analogies to think about descriptions and explanations in general, but, really, it's totally useless for comparing actual scientific theories of empirical sciences. (It was also never intended to be used to do that.) There is no empirical science in which we can make a neat distinction between the descriptions of phenomena and theoretic explanations and then calculate some complexity measure of the theory as a whole (all the explanations, in relation to each other and to other sciences).
It's of course possible to see the idea of compressibility as a variant of Occam's Razor. But Occam's Razor has a much broader sense as a heuristic rule of thumb, an esthetic preference for "simplicity" or for "elegance" in theories. It's not possible to completely capture this vague sense in a quantitative measure. And simplicity is really in the eye of the beholder. If theories can be simplified, fine and good, but there is no reason why nature would need to be "simple" or conform to human ideas of what is "beautiful".
In other words, "ontological complexity of a theory" is a string of meaningless words. The words have no operational meaning.

To add to this; Occam's Razor gets a lot of use and abuse from plenty of intellectually dishonest folks. In the end, while I'd agree the simpler explanation is more likely in many cases, try telling that to your friendly neighbourhood quantum physicist (provided they're conscious and sober)

Maybe we could say: science prefers simple theories to explain complicated things? So if God is actually 'simple' science will run smack in to that eventually. If otherwise, science will always run away from God as an explanation, because that's not the goal of science. This probably seems intuitive to many people.

What is 'simpler' in one sense (a shorter bitstring) is more complicated in another (more random). Chaitin's number Omega (the halting probability of an arbitrary turing machine) really contains all answers to all solvable questions, but unfortunately it is uncomputable and just as useless as Borges' Library of Babel. The answers are all "there" - somewhere - but the problem is to find and identify answers for our current open problems.
